# Duplicate column name error while creating view

Tags: sql, oracle

This related to my question here [Getting Error while creating a view in oracle DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852402/getting-error-while-creating-a-view-in-oracle-db)

I tried the below,but getting duplicate Error column at line 6

```
CREATE VIEW ReturnCode90
AS
  SELECT t.ret_code,
       TO_CHAR (t.creation_dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') Created_Date,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Curr_tmp,
       t.* 
  FROM buff.log t
  WHERE t.ret_Code = '90' 
 order by t.creation_dt desc;
```

Comment: what are all the column names of t.*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are creating a view with the same column `ret_code`  twice; if you the same column to appera twice in the view, you need to use an alias for one of the two occurrences:

```
CREATE VIEW ReturnCode90
AS
  SELECT t.ret_code as someAlias,
       TO_CHAR (t.imx_creation_dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') Created_Date,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Curr_tmp,
       t.* 
  FROM imxbuff.bank_imx_pmt_head t
  WHERE t.ret_Code = '90' 
 order by t.imx_creation_dt desc;
```

If you don't want this, you can remove the column from the select list

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (t.imx_creation_dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') Created_Date,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Curr_tmp,
       t.*
```

or, better, explicitly write the column names instead of using `*`:

```
  SELECT t.ret_code,
       TO_CHAR (t.imx_creation_dt, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') Created_Date,
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP Curr_tmp,
       t.otherColumn1,
       t.otherColumn2,
       ...
```